# Refreshing a fileSystemViewer in java

Tags: java, filesystems, jtree

Im Trying to develop a small application that uses a gui to move files from anywhere on the system. I have the code to move the files and they do indeed move when selected and buttons pressed but I dont know how to refresh the filesystem viewer to reflect the change. The code I have to set up the system viewer is below:

```
public class FileMover  {
//Start of Global Variables
private JTree tree;
private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
private FileSystemView fileSystemView;
protected File currentFile;
protected LinkedList fileLocations;
protected JTree movedTree;
protected JPanel areaLeft;
protected JPanel areaRight;
protected JPanel areaMiddle;
protected final JFrame openFrame;
//end of global variables.

//Constructor for FileMover
public FileMover()
{
    openFrame = new JFrame("File Mover");
    createFileMover();

}
public void createFileMover(){

    Container contentPane = this.openFrame.getContentPane();
    fileLocations = new LinkedList();


    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    areaLeft = new JPanel();
    areaRight = new JPanel();
    areaMiddle = new JPanel();

    contentPane.add(areaLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
    contentPane.add(areaRight, BorderLayout.EAST);
    contentPane.add(areaMiddle, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    areaLeft.add(createSystemView());
    movedTree = new JTree(fileLocations.toArray());
    JScrollPane movedPane = new JScrollPane(movedTree);
    JButton moveRightButton = new JButton("->");
    JButton moveLeftButton = new JButton("<-");
    JButton refresh = new JButton("Refresh");

    areaMiddle.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    areaMiddle.add(moveRightButton);
    areaMiddle.add(refresh);
    areaMiddle.add(moveLeftButton);

    //actualy move the file

    moveRightButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            System.out.println("Moving file: "+ currentFile.getName());
            fileLocations.add(currentFile);
            try {
                //move the file to the correct location.
                moveFile(currentFile);


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FileMover.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println(fileLocations.getFirst().toString());
        }
    });

    //refresh the gui
    refresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            refresh();
        }
    });

    //finish setting up the frame
    openFrame.setSize(1280, 768);
    openFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    openFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    openFrame.setResizable(false);
    openFrame.pack();
    openFrame.setVisible(true);


}

/** Add the files that are contained within the directory of this node.
*/
private void showChildren(final DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    tree.setEnabled(false);


    SwingWorker<Void, File> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, File>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            File file = (File) node.getUserObject();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                File[] files = fileSystemView.getFiles(file, true); //!!
                if (node.isLeaf()) {
                    for (File child : files) {

                            publish(child);

                    }
                }

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<File> chunks) {
            for (File child : chunks) {
                node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {

            tree.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}

/** Update the File details view with the details of this File. */
private void setFileDetails(File file) {
    System.out.println("Path: "+ file.getPath());
    System.out.println("Name: "+ fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file));


}
private void refresh(){
    //refresh the tree here

}
private JScrollPane createSystemView(){
    //file syatem hierarchy
    fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();    

    // the File tree
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

        TreeSelectionListener treeSelectionListener = new TreeSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent tse){
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node =
                    (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tse.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
                showChildren(node);
                setFileDetails((File)node.getUserObject());
                currentFile = (File)node.getUserObject();
            }
        };

        // show the file system roots.
        File[] roots = fileSystemView.getRoots();
        for (File fileSystemRoot : roots) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(fileSystemRoot);
            root.add( node );
            File[] files = fileSystemView.getFiles(fileSystemRoot, true);
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file));
                }
            }

        }

        tree = new JTree(treeModel);
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(treeSelectionListener);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new FileTreeCellRenderer());
        tree.expandRow(0);
        JScrollPane treeScroll = new JScrollPane(tree);
        tree.setVisibleRowCount(15);

        Dimension preferredSize = treeScroll.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension widePreferred = new Dimension(
            200,
            (int)preferredSize.getHeight());
        treeScroll.setPreferredSize( widePreferred );

        return treeScroll;
}
```

The move left button and the area right are not finished but what I need is when I select a node in the tree and click the right arrow button the file/folder the node reflects is moved internally by my moveFile code and that works. but that change is not reflected in the tree so how can show this change in the tree i.e refresh the tree to show the current state of the filesystem?

I've tried treeModel.reload(); but that doesnt seem to work and throws a null pointer exception.

I've tried :

```
areaLeft.removeAll();

areaLeft.add(createSystemView());
```

thinking that it may refresh it by recreating the system view but that doesnt seem to do anything.

Help here would be most appreciated!

Edit: Below is the requested code for the file tree renderer:

```
/** A TreeCellRenderer for a File. */
class FileTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7799441088157759804L;

private FileSystemView fileSystemView;

private JLabel label;

FileTreeCellRenderer() {
    label = new JLabel();
    label.setOpaque(true);
    fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
}

@Override
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(
    JTree tree,
    Object value,
    boolean selected,
    boolean expanded,
    boolean leaf,
    int row,
    boolean hasFocus) {

    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;
    File file = (File)node.getUserObject();
    label.setIcon(fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file));
    label.setText(fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file));
    label.setToolTipText(file.getPath());

    if (selected) {
        label.setBackground(backgroundSelectionColor);
        label.setForeground(textSelectionColor);
    } else {
        label.setBackground(backgroundNonSelectionColor);
        label.setForeground(textNonSelectionColor);
    }

    return label;
}
}
```

Comment: pls post code for FileTreeCellRenderer

Comment: to be faster, when I press the refresh button you want the tree to refresh to current FS contents? (as I see it does not currently) ?

Comment: that is correct, initially i wanted it to refresh automatically when I move files to and from diffrent places but for now the refresh button will do the refresh of the FS contents. so after every move refresh will show the FS again with the files where they should now be

Answer (score 1):

Since from your code it looks that you know what you're doing, I'll just show the elementary example which will *only work for the first time* you press the refresh button:

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode someNode;
private void refresh(){
    System.out.println(someNode);
    treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(someNode);
}
```

and rewrite the part of createSystemView() like this:

```
        int  cnt = 0;
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {                    
                if ((cnt++) == 5) {                        //1
                    System.out.println(file.getPath());
                    node.add(someNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file));
                }
                else {
                    node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file));
                }
            }
        }
```

This will only work if you have *at least six* (comment 1) directories on your root. Run the file, count the directories from root - when you press the refresh button it'll remove the sixth directory. If you press the button again it will try to remove the already removed node so you'll get an IllegalArgumentException.

You need to call [removeNodeFromParent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#removeNodeFromParent%28javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode%29) on the [treeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html):

> Message this to remove node from its parent. This will message nodesWereRemoved to create the appropriate event. This is the preferred way to remove a node as it handles the event creation for you.

See this [example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.tree/RemNode.html) also.

If you want to refresh the entire view you should recreate the model in the refersh function as you do in initialization, or just iterate the model and update as neccessary - but I'd suggest a   [breadth first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) of the model in that case.

EDIT:

"so after every move refresh will show the FS again with the files where they should now be". Let's start with reinitializing the model, by that I solely mean the treeModel instance of [DefaultTreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html) class.

So, in the refresh() method you create a new treeModel instance, and fill it with DefaultMutableTreeNode instances like you did in createSystemView() method:

```
 DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
 treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
 File[] roots = fileSystemView.getRoots();
    for (File fileSystemRoot : roots) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(fileSystemRoot);
        root.add( node );
        File[] files = fileSystemView.getFiles(fileSystemRoot, true);
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file));
            }
        }
    }
```

We have prepared the model, now we need to set it to the tree, I believe that a mere:

```
tree.setModel(treeModel);
```

should suffice, notice that you do not need to add the listener, because the setModel method  reattaches the listeners from old model to the new model and also notifies the JTree view to redraw itself accordingly - I checked the source. If it won't redraw (I doubt it, but I haven't tested this) force it in the next line like this:

```
treeModel.reload();
```

APIdoc  for reload() method  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#reload%28%29).

If however you want to update the model in the refresh function, which I believe would be more natural operation for an action called "refresh", you'll need to obtain the new first level directories and then traverse the tree like this (since we're traversing all the root's children, it would be the mentioned breadth-first traversal):

```
int firstLevelCount = treeModel.getChildCount(root);
DefaultMutableTreeNode child;
for (int i=0; i < firstLevelCount; i++) {
   child = treeModel.getChild(root, index); 
   // update logic part 1
}
// update logic part 2
treeModel.reload();
```

You'll  need the [DefaultMutableTreeNode.getUserObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#getUserObject%28%29) method which will return a file that that tree node represents.

Obviously, you ll want to remove all the nodes from the model that are not in the the new files array, and for all the files that don't have their correspondent node in the model, you'll want to add them to the model.

I would advise not to use the files array but list (so that you could benefit from the [List.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method) e.g.

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getRoots()));
```

Also, rewrite a part of your renderer like this:

```
if (file != null) {
    label.setIcon(fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file));
    label.setText(fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file));
    label.setToolTipText(file.getPath());
}
```

because the root node in your view doesn't have associated file so you'll most probably get an [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) at some time updating the model.

In the second variant I described, you might get tempted to remove the root child node from inside the loop (at the update logic 1 part) - if you do that you'll most probably get an [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). The solution is to make another

```
List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();
```

and at //update logic part 1 place (insde the loop) instead of removing the nodes from the model, you put it in that list. When you're done iterating the loop, you simply iterate over that list and remove them from the model at //update logic part 2 place e.g.

```
for (DefaultMutableTreeNode node : toBeRemoved) {
    treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(node);
}
```

As mentioned, this will automatically trigger the view (JTree) redraw, so see what best fits your need.

EDIT^2:

Regarding the second variant of your refresh method, you already have the

```
private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
```

as a global variable, you obtain the root of the tree like this ([getRoot()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#getRoot%28%29))

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)treeModel.getRoot();
```

and as you already did, you obtain the current state of the filesystem like this:

```
FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getRoots();
```

these are all the variables you need to write the refresh() method as described.

Regarding the move (the buttons with arrows (<- , ->)) operation, from inside your treeSelectionListener make this variable global:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tse.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
```

With this variable (let's call it selectedNode), you can make use of the DefaultTreeModel methods:

- [removeNodeFromParent(MutableTreeNode node)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#removeNodeFromParent%28javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode%29)
- [insertNodeInto(MutableTreeNode newChild,MutableTreeNode parent,int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#insertNodeInto%28javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode, javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode, int%29)

Note that both methods will trigger JTree redraw. This should be sufficient to implement the operations you described. Also, you could rewrite the moveButton actionListener method like this:

```
moveRightButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (selectedNode != null) {
             //all the move-code-refresh-tre-view-here
             selectedNode = null;
        }
    }
});
```

the selectedNode will only be set by treeSelectionListener, so in this manner you are sure that the the file move operation will only take place if a file is actually selected in the tree view.

Comment: When you say recreate the model in the refresh function which is pretty much what I want to do, I tried something like this but it doesnt seem to work, the file I move still appears: private void refresh(){
        JScrollPane newScroll = new JScrollPane(createSystemView());
        this.areaLeft.removeAll();
        this.areaLeft.add(newScroll);
        this.openFrame.repaint();
        
    }

Comment: you tried to reinitialize teh *UI* not the *model*. See you tomorrow

Comment: With your first solution of refreshing the model, I am getting a null pointer exception in the tree.setModel() method. And for your second solution i'm not quite sure I understand what to put in the update logic 1 & 2, are you saying remove every single node or just the node that has been moved and add the node when its moved back

Comment: have you rewritten the renderer as I showed? update, refresh model ="remove just the node that has been moved and add the node when its moved back" exactly.

Comment: I have rewritten the renderer and it compiles and runs but still the moved file is appearing in the viewer after being moved and refresh pressed. Could you explain your second method more clearly as in where you get your variables from in terms of my code?

Comment: yes. that was what you asked, no? I will update post in couple of hours regarding the "in terms of your code". Do you want the filesystem state to be seen (after every *outside* change) in your tree *without* pressing the refresh button?

Comment: What I would like to happen is when a file is moved after pressing the -> button, it dissappears from the tree, and when its brought back, it reappears in the tree, in particular,I've modified my own code to ensure that the file moves back to a selected directory i.e: select a directory in the tree, press the move back button <- and it moves there, what I'd like to see is that move happen in the tree too, so the file appears under that directory in the tree after the button is pressed, if this cant happen then the refresh button will make it appear once clicked